# .Net EF records are not saved in the database (InvalidOperationException)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have tables: Vendor and Brand and base abstract class

```
public abstract class Entity<TEntity, TKeyType> : IEntity<TEntity, TKeyType>
    where TEntity : class
{
    [Key]
    public virtual TKeyType ID { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    #region Equals
    public virtual bool Equals(Entity<TEntity, TKeyType> other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
        if (other == null || !(other is TEntity))
            return false;
        return ID.Equals(other.ID);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var compareTo = obj as Entity<TEntity, TKeyType>;
        return Equals(compareTo);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Entity:

```
public partial class Vendor : Entity<Vendor, long>
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Vendor()
    {
        Brand = new HashSet<Brand>();
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Brand> Brand { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Brand : Entity<Brand, long>
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Brand()
    {
        SubBrand = new HashSet<SubBrand>();
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    
    public long VendorID { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

ODMSDBContext:

```
public partial class ODMSDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ODMSDBContext() : base("name=ODMSConnection") { }

    public virtual DbSet<Vendor> Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Brand> Brand { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
            .Property(e => e.ExtraCode)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
            .HasMany(e => e.SubBrand)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Brand)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BrandID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Brand)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Vendor)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.VendorID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

---

in Service exist method - Create

```
    public override void Create(IEnumerable<EntityModel> models)
    {
        var entities = new List<Brand>();

        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            var entityModel = model as BrandModel;
            var entity = new Brand
            {
                Guid = entityModel.Guid,
                VendorID = entityModel.VendorID,
                Name = entityModel.Name,
                SortOrder = entityModel.SortOrder,
                ExtraCode = entityModel.ExtraCode
            };

            entities.Add(entity);
        }
        _repository.Create(entities);

        _repository.Save();
    }
```

---

and sample of code from Repository (_repository)

```
public class EntityRepository<TEntity, TKeyType> : IEntityRepository<ODMSDBContext, TEntity, TKeyType>
where TEntity : class, IEntity<TEntity, TKeyType>
{
    private readonly ODMSDBContext _context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> DbSet => _context.Set<TEntity>();

    public EntityRepository(ODMSDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    ...
    
    public void Create(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        DbSet.AddRange(entities);
    }
    
    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

on saving I get an error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The operation failed: The relationship could not be > changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

before saving I checked Brand. Vendor in most of all is null, but VendorID is filled.
I tried to add this in Service in method Create

```
Vendor = _vendorRepository.GetById(entityModel.VendorID)
```

but after AddRange data from Vendor field are disappeared %)

upd. I have created small video that describe strange behaviour - http://screencast.com/t/RI32v4gu

Comment: Where is `SubBrand` code?

Comment: @grek40 I think it doesn't matter. code is similar as in Brand, nothing new. do you think is it important ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a Key data annotation or you setting the actual keys up in Fluent API.

Try changing your modelBuilder overrides to explicitly set the foreign keys on each entity.

```cs
    public partial class ODMSDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public ODMSDBContext() : base("name=ODMSConnection") { }

        public virtual DbSet<Vendor> Vendor { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Brand> Brand { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
                .Property(e => e.ExtraCode)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
                .Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
                .HasMany(e => e.SubBrand)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Brand)
                .HasForeignKey(e=>e.ID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
                .Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Brand)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Vendor)
                .HasForeignKey(e=>e.ID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For `Vendor`, we see `VendorID` in the question. Would be a better fit than `ID` as foreign key. Other than this detail, looks like a good catch, I overlooked the missing foreign key specification.

Comment: I have added `HasForeignKey(e => e.ID)` to Vendor and receiver an error:
_Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Vendor_Brand_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Vendor_Brand_Target' in relationship 'Vendor_Brand'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'._

Comment: @evg.vis Thats why you should say `HasForeignKey(e => e.VendorID)` instead.

Comment: @grek40 yes, you are right, I added `HasForeignKey(e => e.VendorID)` and added attribute `[Key]` to field `ID` in my `abstract class Entity`, but it is not solved my problem

Comment: @evg.vis Please update the question code, so it's clear how exactly you did the modification.

Comment: @grek40 I have updated the question and add link to small video (in the end of question)

Answer (score 0):

I need to say sorry for wasting your time. I hasn't copied all my code for abstract class Entity and that's why you couldn't help me. In abstract class Entity, I have realized base methods for comparing.

When I tried to add new Brands to Vendor, field ID in all Brands was equal to 0. This value was compare to exist in HashSet, with the help of my Base Methods for Comparing, and new records were not added because Brand with ID = 0 does exist in this list.

I have commented Base Methods for Comparing and everything is working :)

ps. splecial thanks to @grek40 ;)

Comment: I'm sometimes revisiting my recent question comments and I'm always glad to see when its solved ;) By the way, you are not the first one with this issue. Problems with not yet initialized entity IDs being treated as unique pop up every so often and are definitely among the tricky beasts. Still I'd prefer it if you write less of an apology & thanks story and more of a structured well explained answer that helps others who might also compare entities by ID without a second thought.